# PHP / MySQL Database Synchronization

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

***Scenario:*** I have a project which reads data from multiple different databases on different hosts with read-only access. All of them store the same type of information (for demo: *Users*).

Every database stores the information in their own way (different table names, column names, types etc.)

Now I want to get every *User* from every database and insert them into my own table '*User*'.

Currently I am doing this by having 2 cronjobs - 1 imports Users & 1 updates Users (Select from Read-Only DB and insert into own DB the way I want).

Now I don't really like the idea of having multiple cronjobs running, just to import/update Users - ***plus*** I want to have the newest data in my database all the time - which means I need to run the cronjobs atleast every minute.

This with multiple tables are way too many minute-cronjobs IMO.

---

**Question:**
Is there any way to achieve the same thing easier? Or is this already the correct way to do so?

Next issue is, that there is in most case no information which data is updated or not - meaning I need to import the same data over and over just to have the newest.

Any help will be gladly appreciated.

---

Using PHP 7+, Mysql with Symfony & Doctrine - if that helps.

Comment: You need to get more control over the databases/sites, you read from, to better optimize this. You seem to imply that that is impossible. Is that true, or is it just an arbitrary restriction you've imposed on yourself?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Sadly, that is correct. I have read-only access - and thats it.
Just of interest - what would your ideal solution be? Thanks =)

Comment: The ideal situation would be where changes could be pushed to your central database.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to find another 'acceptable' solution for my case then.

Comment: An alternative is to use [federated tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create.html) so you can use the remote tables as though they are local and then create a view that will have the data in the way you want them. Views can be pre-loaded and only updated manually if you choose to do this otherwise by default they'll rebuild on demand. Your cronjob approach is pretty good though imo I probably would just stick with that until I encounter issues with it